# What does a value = -1 mean for the GRASS v.to.db module?

Tags: shapefile, grass-gis

I need to identify the adjacent polygones of each polygon of my shapefile. I've applied methodology described [here](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_length_of_common_boundaries) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70164/trying-to-extract-arc-information-from-a-suburb-shapefile/70237#70237).

as a result, the columns (left, right) have all a value of -1.

I find no information about the meaning of this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [v.to.db](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.to.db.html) help `-1` refers to `NULL` or `-` category and if `no category` is found

> v.to.db loads vector map features or metrics into a database table, or
>   prints them (or the SQL queries used to obtain them) in a form of a
>   human-readable report. For uploaded/printed category values '-1' is
>   used for 'no category' and 'null' / '-' if category cannot be found or
>   multiple categories were found. For line azimuths '-1' is used for
>   closed lines (start equals end).

You can check the help in the above link.

Comment: Thanks ahmadhanb, but I really don't understand why I get this result. And don't know which way to try to find.

Comment: Did you follow the steps mentioned in the link you provided in your question: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_length_of_common_boundaries. You need to categorize with polygon is right and which polygon is left. Actually, I did not do it before, but it looks like you need to use v.category before v.to.db.

Comment: Here is my code python : (I still don't know how to format, sorry) `code`grass.run_command("v.voronoi", input=centroids_pt, output='tmp_wk1',  overwrite='True', stdout = DEVNULL, stderr = DEVNULL)
grass.run_command("v.overlay", ainput='tmp_wk1', binput=basin_limit, 
                               operator='and',  output=tmp_voronoi, overwrite=True, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)

Comment: grass.run_command("v.category", input=tmp_voronoi, layer='2', 
                                option='add', type='boundary',
                                output='tmp_wk2', overwrite=True)
grass.run_command("v.db.addtable", map='tmp_wk2', layer='2', 
                                   columns='left integer, right integer')

grass.run_command("v.to.db", map='tmp_wk2',
                             layer='2', query_layer='2',
                             option='sides', 
                             column='left,right')

Comment: So,  I think I've followed the steps but I surely miss something. A new glance on my code should help

Comment: @Christine It is better to post a new question with the detailed description of your problem including the code that post in the comment. You can format the code properly in the question area. As per the GIS.SE you can only ask one question at a time.